# How to get Tags from pdf document in c#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdf-reader

I am using iTextSharp to read a pdf document and it is getting read successfully. Now I want to get Tags from a pdf document but I don't know how to get tags using iTextSharp.

Code is given below

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = pdfText(@"C:\Users\Purelogics\Desktop\tranfer\tagged.pdf");
    }

    public static string pdfText(string path)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
        //This line return true that means this document is tagged
        bool isTagged = reader.IsTagged();
        var metadeta = reader.Metadata;
        IList<Dictionary<string, object>> bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(reader);
        string text = string.Empty;
        var title = reader.Info["Title"];
        for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            var object1 = reader.GetPdfObject(page);
            text += PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page);
        }
        reader.Close();
        return text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to do with this tagging exactly.
Let's assume you want to extract everything tagged as `\P` (paragraphs)

First you need to get the structuretree root of a document

```
File inputFile = new File("input.pdf");
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(inputFile));
IStructureNode root = pdfDocument.getStructTreeRoot();
```

Now that you have the structuretree root, you can crawl the tree. Either via a stack, or recursion. In this example, I am using recursion.

```
private Set<PdfNameMCIDGroup> find(PdfDocument pdfDocument, IStructureNode node){
    Set<PdfNameMCIDGroup> out = new HashSet<>();

    PdfName role = node.getRole();
    if(markedRoles.contains(role))
        out.add(mark(pdfDocument, node));
    else
        for(IStructureNode kid : node.getKids())
            out.addAll(find(pdfDocument, kid));

    return out;
}
```

And this is what the `mark` method looks like

```
private PdfNameMCIDGroup mark(PdfDocument pdfDocument, IStructureNode node){
    PdfNameMCIDGroup out = new PdfNameMCIDGroup(0);

    Set<PdfMcr> leaves = new HashSet<>();
    Stack<IStructureNode> stk = new Stack<>();
    stk.push(node);
    while(!stk.isEmpty()){
        IStructureNode tmp = stk.pop();
        if(tmp instanceof PdfMcr)
            leaves.add((PdfMcr) tmp);
        else
            for(IStructureNode kid : tmp.getKids())
                stk.push(kid);
    }

    // mcids
    for(PdfMcr mcr : leaves){
        int mcid = mcr.getMcid();
        int pageNr = pdfDocument.getPageNumber(mcr.getPageObject());
        out.mcids.add(mcid);
        out.pageNrs.add(pageNr);
    }

    return out;
}
```

The idea behind these methods is that `find` will traverse the tree hierarchy. And `mark` will handle the node as soon as it matches one of the roles.

This code gets us halfway to a solution.
We now have the marked content IDs of whatever content is marked with `\P`

We now need to actually extract the rendering instructions that match these IDs.

For this, you need to write your own `IEventListener`. This class can be passed to a `CanvasProcessor`, and will then get notified everytime the parser has finished processing an instruction.

```
public void eventOccurred(IEventData iEventData, EventType eventType) {
    if(eventType == EventType.RENDER_TEXT)
    {
        TextRenderInfo tri = (TextRenderInfo) iEventData;
        int mcID = tri.getMcid();
        // this is where you can do something with it
    }
}
```